# Sending video URL from a web part to media web part created dynamically?

Tags: development, javascript, video-richmedia

Here is a simple scenario I need to send a video URL from one page to another. The page from where the URL comes is a web part and it will display a set of video previews, on click of which a new window opens and video plays in a media player web part, dynamically created. The problem here is that I am not able to pass the video URL from that preview web part to the media player web part page. Since the media player is dynamically created the url would be sufficient. If i set that it would be set as video source and therefore video will play.

Kindly see if any of you have faced similar issues? any sort of input is welcome thanks in advance.

Comment: You could pass the url as query string parameter.

Comment: can you give an example? and please bear in mind that its a model dialog box which pops up and is supposed to play the video.

Answer (score 1):

Create your dialog window parameters as below:

```
var options = {
  url:'', // ur video player page url with querystring parmeter as the data u want to get it  
             in payer page.
  title:'Title, Description, and Icon',
  width:640,
  height:400
}
```

Now read the querystring value in the player page and use it the way you want.

Comment: sorry mate its not carriying the page url